# Vue JS - Reactive content in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display the data of a component, based on whether a property is true or false to keep everything reactive. To do this I started by creating an array of objects 'premiumContent' with each object representing the type of content I want to display in the component. One of these objects should be visible whether 'premiumActivated' is true or not. Can someone kindly walk me through a solution to achieve this? I'm fairly new to this so I tend to mix things up when it comes to syntax.

MyComponent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="background-div">
      <div class="page-info-inner">
          <PremiumContent v-for="item in premiumContent"
                          :key="item.infoText" 
                          :info-text="item.infoText" 
                          :button-text="item.buttonText"
                          :button-callback="null"
                          :subscription-text="item.subscriptionText"
                          :is-visible="item.isVisible" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import PremiumContent from '../../../components/partials/settings/Premium';
  
  export default {
    name: 'MyComponent',
    components: {PremiumContent},
    data: () => ({
      premiumActivated: false,
      
      premiumContent: [
        {
          infoText: "this is the content that should appear if premiumActivated is false",
          buttonText: "button text",
          // isVisible: 'if premium activated === false > show this object'
        },
        {
          infoText: "this is the content that should appear if premiumActivated is true",
          buttonText: "button text",
          subscriptionText: 'extra text',
          // isVisible: 'if premium activated === true > show this object'
        },
      ]
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-show` or `v-if` with `item.isVisible`.

v-show will render the element but keep it hidden and v-if will not render it until isVisible is true.